# Mobile app development for beginners

Tags: android, ios, mobile, social-networking, mbaas

I'm a beginner in mobile app development. Am planning to develop an app related to social networking. Curious to understand the best possible resources to start with. I see some websites like apparchitect.com which help to create a mobile app easily. But I'm not able to figure out how the backend works. Can anyone guide me on how I can proceed with UI and the backend? Are there any tools or platforms available in cloud which will help me to quicken my mobile app development especially social networking apps?

Comment: Huge question. Depending on your background. Take a look at Parse.com and tutos for back end server. It s one suggestion among many others. Books on mobile app devt for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question but i can understand it is difficult for beginners to approach as you don't know where to start, you can design user interface using google's IDE or eclipse, stick to that at least for the start before you move to advanced or custom UI design

for back-end there are many choices including but not limited to sql, sql lite, many other sql based products this list can get quite long, however i'd suggest parse.com it is easy to implement and reliable cloud based service or you could look at similar services usually they don't charge until your app gets to a certain request/traffic limit

if you can afford below sites offer good training content

https://teamtreehouse.com/home

http://www.pluralsight.com/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/category/android (paid plus free content)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

That's a broad question.  You can look at Android tutorials on teamtreehouse.com and look into using Parse.com for the backend.  At least one of the teamtreehouse Android tutorials focuses on Parse.com, and another tutorial focuses on UI layout.

Comment: one doubt "Parse.com for the backend" -> Is it possible that we can use parse.com to host our own API ? parse.com provides any DB such as mysql ?

Comment: No Parse.com would not host your API, you could instead use the Parse API, and have Parse manage all your data reads and data writes for you.  I understand for some cases you may instead want a custom database.  But first checkout Parse.com to see if it would meet your needs, and you could save a lot of time and effort.